# jQuery this selector

Tags: jquery

I did a little Googling, and I couldn't find more information about the `$(this)`. I feel a little silly asking, but I am want to know how exactly does it work. I think I read that it turns the element into an object, but I couldn't find additional information on this. If anyone could provide resources, it would be great.

I am actually trying to understand this question that I asked earlier: [How can I fade only 1 div on mouseover when the classes applies to 5 other divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722043/how-can-i-fade-only-1-div-on-mouseover-when-the-classes-applies-to-5-other-divs)

I just want a thorough explanation for what is happening any why did it work `$(this)`.

Comment: in those examples there are serveral divs, so `$(this)` is used to target the hovered div and not the others.

Comment: I would also recommend some further reading about `this` - [More than you ever wanted to know about `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal/134149#134149)

Comment: @andyb Thanks, this is the kind of stuff that I wanted to read.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a special work in JS. It stands for "the context I am in at the current moment." So, in your example, `this` referred to the *specific* div which had the test class that currently had the mouse over it (wow, confusing there... see below). $() is a wrapper around an object which returns a jQuery object instead of the element directly.

So,

1. `$("div.test").mouseenter` assigns a listener so that when a mouse enters the div it fires
2. `this` inside of that function refers to the specific div entered.
3. `$()` always returns a jQuery augmented version of whatever is inside the parens.

Answer (score 1):

`this` talks about the owner.  So in your question earlier, you had

```
$(".test").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
}).mouseleave(function() {               
    $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

And why `this` works is because you can think of it essentially as a pointer to the specific object that's calling the function.  When you have a `string` as a selector, it will match every element of that selector.  But `this` uniquely points at one object.  And then when you add `$()` around it, it will select that SPECIFIC object that invoked the event.

I would take a look at [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) for a good article.

Comment: I read the article, and you said "And then when you add $() around it, it will select that SPECIFIC object that invoked the event." Wouldn't that mean `.test` was the owner and that would make `.test` `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` when I want `.innerDiv` to `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`?

Comment: I really liked this article, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want a thorough explanation for what is happening any why did it work `$(this)`.

Here you go.

Functions in JavaScript are called *in a context*. They are, in fact, standalone and only loosely coupled to the objects they belong to. It is perfectly possible to call a function that "belongs" to to object B *in the context of* object A, as confusing as it might be at first.

The `this` keyword transports the context for the function call. It contains the object the function *has been called on*.

```
function test() {
  alert(this);
}
// when called in a browser, this will alert "DOMWindow"
```

When no special context is given, the *global* context (in form of the `window` object, when it comes to JavaScript in a browser) is the default.

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function test2() {
  alert(this.push);
}
// this will alert "undefined"
// (as there is no "push" property on the window object)
```

But as I said, you can change the *context* a function is called in. The function that does that is aptly named `call()` and accepts a parameter that determines the meaning of `this` in the function body:

```
test2.call(x);
// this will alert "function push() { [native code] }"
// (as the "push" property on x happens to be a function)
```

Now, this is very useful and jQuery does it a lot:

```
$(".test");       // returns an array of elements of CSS class "test"

$(".test").click( // binds a callback for the "click" event on all of them
  function () {
    // note how there is no context given for the callback function
    alert(this);
  }
);
```

When the click event occurs, the callback function you gave is invoked by jQuery like this

```
callback.call(affectedDOMElement)
```

And, magically, the `this` keyword has a useful meaning in the callback function body.

Answer (score 0):

"`this`" is a javascript thing that can be fairly confusing, here's an in-depth discussion: http://alebelcor.blogspot.com/2011/07/this-keyword-in-javascript.html

In the context of your other post, `this` just refers to the element that you clicked on. By calling the $() function with `this` as an argument, you're just getting the jQuery-fied object of the element you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

`this` within a jQuery event callback usually refers to the DOM element being acted upon.

For example:

```
$('a.foobar').click(function() {
    alert(this.href);
});
```

By wrapping `this` in `$(...)`, you are turning it in to a jQuery object that references (in the example) the clicked link.